# JHipster project deployed using aws sub-generator returns http 404 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-404, jhipster

This question about "**aws sub-generator**" (not "aws-containers sub-generator").

Question 1:
**Is this generator supposed to update "application-prod.yml"?** I can see the information I provided while running the sub-generator including the database name in ".yo-rc.json". But database user-name and password are neither there nor in the "application-prod.yml".

Question 2:
I generated a simple JHipster project with some entities. It was working fine locally on my PC. I used the "aws sub-generator" and everything went well. It created the Elastic Beanstalk application, an EC2 instance, the S3 bucket, the RDS database, the security groups...Here is the event log of the Elastic Beanstalk:

```
Successfully launched environment: alirezatodoapplicationapril-env
Environment health has been set to GREEN
Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-18WDVCSH132VM
Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-EA2GT2HFN77U
Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:827968211260:scalingPolicy:5cf0c635-40b7-4008-9ebe-57823a3f9b3c:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1SLCXWGKICYGM:policyName/awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-JHTI8C9VQTF1
Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:827968211260:scalingPolicy:5e6f86c4-79f7-4504-a6d2-8a8a9c638ef5:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1SLCXWGKICYGM:policyName/awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-E1W03HEXTE6R
Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1SLCXWGKICYGM
Added EC2 instance 'i-074488994cedde8c7' to Auto Scaling Group 'awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1SLCXWGKICYGM'.
Adding instance 'i-074488994cedde8c7' to your environment.
Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-1F3VDL1LKSD1B
Created load balancer named: awseb-e-i-AWSEBLoa-18MWGKA8O6FHP
Created security group named: awseb-e-i2vaqsmdbh-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1BS14HUVJLFUD
Created security group named: sg-874777cd
Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-827968211260 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
createEnvironment is starting.
```

But, now when I use the link of the Beanstalk application it gives me a **404 error**. What is missed? Here is the log of application startup (catalina.out):

```
        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2018-07-31 20:18:22.679 ERROR 3398 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/ToDo/prod/master": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:218)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:96)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
    ... 24 common frames omitted

31-Jul-2018 20:18:22.688 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:136)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/config/ToDo/prod/master": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:218)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:96)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
    ... 24 more

31-Jul-2018 20:18:22.690 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

31-Jul-2018 20:18:22.691 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [16,376] ms
31-Jul-2018 20:18:22.695 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
31-Jul-2018 20:18:22.727 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
31-Jul-2018 20:18:22.742 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 16499 ms
```

Comment: You chose to use Eureka for service discovery, so you need to launch the JHipster Registry when running in prod.  That's what the connection error is referring to

Comment: @JonRuddell Thanks! When did I choose Eureka? I guess I was not asked about it neither when using the sub-generator nor creating the project.

Comment: It's one of the prompts when generating a project https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/prompts.js#L86-L101

Comment: @JonRuddell So, that "Yes" means Eureka. Is there anyway I change the project not to use JHipster Registery or I have to generate a new project and merge my code? It's just a simple monolithic project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JHipster AWS ElasticBeanstalk option only works with monoliths and won't deploy the JHipster Registry if that option is chosen when generating the project.

If you want to disable the JHipster Registry feature, you can set two config variables in your project.  In bootstrap-prod.yml, set `spring.cloud.config.enabled: false` and disable Eureka in application-prod.yml with `eureka.client.enabled: false`.

In regards to the database connection settings, those are set as environment variables [when creating the ElasticBeanstalk environment](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/234431b607fa7cb5a5e09224f1aafdcceed9c907/generators/aws/lib/eb.js#L134-L156) which Spring Boot uses instead of the hardcoded config in application-prod.yml

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information!
What if it was a Microservice-based project? Would "JHipster Registery" be deployed via "aws-containers sub-generator"?
And why this change is "temporarily"? Can't I leave the changed configuration like that for ever?

Comment: I believe so (because microservices usually require it) but I haven't tried.  I removed the word "temporarily"

Comment: Thanks for being a big help! May I ask what is your favorite way to deploy a JHipster project? For both monolith and microservice.

Comment: My favorite is Docker + Rancher for both monoliths/microservices, but there are so many options I haven't tried yet.  For microservices, I can't imagine deploying without containers

Comment: And for those who are reading this question/answer, if you're running the project locally after the deployment, you'll need to put the database-server address and the credentials for database user in application-prod.yml since the project will run in prod. If you're cloning a deployed project from git, then it will probably run in dev profile unless you deploy it again.